# instant messaging with intel xdk receiving notification on new message

Tags: cross-platform, intel-xdk, instant-messaging

i would like to create instant messaging in cross platform. how can i get the application keep listening to the server so when there is a message coming, the application could receive a notification.
maybe like service in android?
I've read about push message (push mobi) but it doesn't seem to meet my need since it blast the notification on all registered id from admin panel, not from 1 id to another id.
i notice GCM but some say it is not suitable for sending and receiving chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a good scenario for websockets. There's a [phongap plugin](https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket) for android that will allow you to use them.

Take a look at the [plugin demo](https://bitbucket.org/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket-demo/src). It looks pretty strait-forward.

client side javascript:

```
  var socket = io.connect("http://10.0.2.2:8080");

  document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = "connecting";

  socket.on('ping', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = data.message;
    socket.emit('pong', { message: 'Hello from client!' });
  });

  socket.on('connect', function () {
     document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = "connected";
  });
});
```

Server side web service in node.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('emit...');
  socket.emit('ping', { message: 'Hello from server ' + Date.now() });
  socket.on('pong', function (data) {
    console.log(data.message);
  });
});

console.log('listening on port 8080');
```

Comment: on the plugin demo, it said that android sdk needed to be installed correctly. does that mean i must use eclipse or it is possible i try it on intel xdk?

Comment: No. You need the JDK and android SDK installed and configured to do android development in general, thats all its saying.

Comment: "configured to do android development in general" does that the one that adding tools and platform-tools into path in environment variable?

Comment: i've tried it and it worked. thankyou, this is also one of the thing i was looking for. but it still doesn't answer my question about the service to get the notification when the application is closed. if i'm not mistaken, with this plugin if the application is closed completely then there is no way i can get notification.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. Push notifications (GCM/APN) are the obvious (to me) choice when your application is closed, and they can be targeted to the registered user/device but they aren't aren't guaranteed to be delivered on time or at all, and there's nothing you can do about it. You can poll your message api in a background task, but those tasks may not run either.

Comment: thankyou, i've successfully create socket.io+GCM android simple apps :)

Comment: how if i want to user domain name instead of ip address?
i use www.example.com (DMZ) for the main domain and using reverse proxy
to access the chat server www.example.com/chat ,translate to my server ip address in blue zone(ex:123.456.0.10)
and www.example.com/chat2, translate to my server ip address in specified port (123.456.0.10:8080)
if i connect directly in web browser with www.example.com/chat2
it's connected "Welcome to socket.io."
but if i use it in socket = io.connect("h ttp://www.example/chat2/");
it won't connect.any idea?